# File not being changed

Tags: java, file, file-writing

I am writing a program that changes any special characters to a space in a file and then re-reads the file and gets a frequency of word length. When run, it seems to run correctly, but when I open up the file, nothing has changed.

```
File tempFile = File.createTempFile("buffer", ".tmp");
fw = new FileWriter(tempFile);
reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(file));
System.out.println("File opened");

String line = reader.readLine();

// Replace non-alphanumeric symbols with spaces
System.out.println("Replacing non-alphanumeric symbols\n");
while(line != null) {
   line = line.replaceAll("a-zA-Z0-9_-", " ");
   fw.write(line);
   line = reader.readLine();                
   }
System.out.println("Lines replaced");
file = tempFile;
reader.close();
```

file is initialized above this segment of code.

Comment: What do you think `file = tempFile;` really does ?

Comment: Have you debugged it to see what is happening at `line.replaceAll("a-zA-Z0-9_-", " ");`?

Comment: Read https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/ for tips on debugging your code.

Comment: @Arminius I am guessing by your comment that it isn't what I thought it did. I thought it wrote over the original file.

Comment: @ndsmith it only makes the `file` variable point to the temp file you write into. Your original file is untouched.

Comment: @Arminius Is it possible to write into the original file over the original line without erasing the rest of the file?

Answer (score 2):

There's a problem in your code.

`line.replaceAll()` is a function and returns a new `String` object with replaced characters.
Your code replaces the given line, but you do not assign the result to any variable.

It should probably look something like this:

```
File tempFile = File.createTempFile("buffer", ".tmp");
fw = new FileWriter(tempFile);
reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(file));
System.out.println("File opened");

String line = reader.readLine();

// Replace non-alphanumeric symbols with spaces
System.out.println("Replacing non-alphanumeric symbols\n");
while(line != null) {
   line = line.replaceAll("a-zA-Z0-9_-", " "); //assign the replaced value to the variable
   fw.write(line);
   line = reader.readLine();                
   }
System.out.println("Lines replaced");
file = tempFile;
reader.close();
```

Comment: Thanks for catching that, but it still did not fix it.

Comment: I fixed it both in the code and the question. Again, thank you.